# Convert .txt to 3 column xlsx format

Tags: python-2.7

I am new in python scripting and I'm working on python 2.7 version and I have data in .txt format as given below

```
DTMTYEAR  LAT.  67.5  68.5  69.5  70.5  71.5  72.5  73.5  74.5  75.5  76.5  77.5  
01011951   7.5 99.90 99.90 99.90 99.90 99.90 99.90 99.90 99.90 99.90 99.90 99.90 
01011951   8.5 99.90 99.90 99.90 99.90 99.90 99.90 31.45 99.90 99.90 30.02 31.19 
01011951   9.5 99.90 99.90 99.90 99.90 99.90 99.90 99.90 99.90 99.90 30.18 29.93 
01011951  10.5 99.90 99.90 99.90 99.90 99.90 99.90 99.90 99.90 29.08 27.62 27.91 
01011951  11.5 99.90 99.90 99.90 99.90 99.90 30.11 99.90 99.90 28.32 27.28 28.28
```

I want this data in xlsx format as given below

```
 x    y     value
7.5 67.5    99.90
7.5 68.5    99.90
7.5 69.5    99.90
7.5 70.5    99.90
7.5 71.5    99.90
7.5 72.5    99.90
7.5 73.5    99.90
7.5 74.5    99.90
7.5 75.5    99.90
7.5 76.5    99.90
7.5 77.5    99.90
8.5 67.5    99.90
8.5 68.5    99.90
```

and so on...

Please help me how to do it.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Please share your code and error if any.

Comment: i dont know how to do it. i am beginner in programming and i m just started to learn python and its very important to me for my college project so please help me....

Comment: Please reply or suggest something...